# Вывод русского текста python

Tags: python, utf-8

Здравствуйте. Имеется программа которая выводит ФИО из базы firebird. Проблема заключается в следующем, вместо ФИО выводиться

```
('FIO ',['\xd0\xa1\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\x90\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9 \xd0\x9f\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87'])
```

Если использовать .join()
то выводиться это `╨б╤В╨╛╤И ╨Р╨╜╨┤╤А╨╡╨╣ ╨Я╨░╨▓╨╗╨╛╨▓╨╕╤З`
Файл настроен под UTf-8 так же прописано `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-`

пример кода

```
FOTO = list(FirebirdLogin.P_FOTO[0])
    print('FIO '.join(FIO))
```

Comment: Пробовали в файл выводить? Возможно, проблема именно в консоли. `open("out.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8").write('FIO '.join(FIO))`

Comment: Откуда  берётся и как исправить `\xd0\xa1...` описано в моём ответе для вопроса-дубликата. Это заодно и `А╨╡╨...` кракозябы исправляет (за подробностями, следуйте по ссылке в ответе).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
FIO = [f.decode('UTF-8') for f in FIO]
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло..